# Passiv und Präteritum - "geboren"

Tags: passive, past

Es steht im Deutsch-kursbuch "Gabriele Münter wird am 19. Februar 1877 in Berlin geboren".

Warum "wird"? (Passiv)

Ich glaube, dass im Präteritum ist. Ich vermute, wir müssen "wurde" oder "war" verwenden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es handelt sich um Passiv, richtig.

> Gabriele Münter wird am 19. Februar 1877 in Berlin geboren.

Dies ist der Ausnahmefall einer Darstellung der Vergangenheit im Präsens. Man leitet so eine lebhaftere Form der Erzählung ein, die den Leser in die damalige Zeit versetzen soll.

> Gabriele Münter wurde am 19. Februar 1877 in Berlin geboren.

Das ist hingegen die konventionelle Form der Erzählung im Präteritum, erneut im Passiv.

Comment: Dieses Stilmittel, über Vergangenes im Präsens zu erzählen, nennt man übrigens "historisches Präsens" (historical present). Es gibt auch die Bezeichnungen "erzählerisches Präsens" oder "narratives Präsens".